# Why does this struct that contains a pointer to itself not work properly?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct minion
{
    int home;
    struct minion *father;  
} Minion;
main()
{
    Minion *dummy = (Minion *)malloc(sizeof(Minion));
    dummy->father = &dummy;
    dummy->home = 0;
    printf("%d %d %d", &dummy, dummy->father, (dummy->father)->father);
}
```

Why is the value of `(dummy->father)->father` different from the others?

The output is:

```
2424368 2424368 43
```

Comment: Is this C or C++?  It looks like C

Comment: This code looks all `C` to me.

Comment: I have a pretty good guess as to why it all looks like C.

Comment: You re assigning "pointer to pointer" to a "pointer": `dummy->father = &dummy;`. This should not compile in c++.

Comment: do not use `typedef struct` it is evil

Comment: @NickZ you cannot forward declare that crap

Comment: Why do you want to store the address of a temporary?

Comment: @Slava How do you mean..? The only downside to `typedef` a `struct` is that you're hiding the fact that it's a struct when it's used in the program.

Comment: The format specifier to format a pointer is _not_ `%d`. It is `%p` (and I think it is strictly speaking necessary to convert the argument pointers to `void*` or `void const*`).

Comment: @NickZ I mean try to forward declare `Minion` to use pointer or reference without including header. Especially when struct is anonymous.

Comment: @Arkadiy unfortunately, at least one popular compiler (gcc) has a bug in that it fails to give an error for incompatible type conversions, in its default mode of operation . This misleads people.

Comment: yeah this code is in c!i tagged c++ because of my distraction

Comment: @Slava: It's not evil, it's merely unnecessary.

Comment: @KeithThompson it is, when you have to use C library in C++ and want to make a wrapper  you have to use `void *` because of this creepiness.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc()` in C code.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/315052)

Comment: @Slava: I don't understand. Do you have an example? Typedefs for structures are as valid (and as unnecessary) in C++ as they are in C.

Comment: @KeithThompson it is pretty common in C library to write `typedef struct { ... } crap;` and then use `crap *` as handles. I do not want to expose C header to the rest of C++ code, so I made thin wrapper to avoid include and I cannot forward declare `crap` to use `crap *` without include. So I have to use `void *` which is unsafe.

Comment: @Slava: `typedef struct crap crap;` works just fine in a header file if the user of the library only needs to use `crap *`.

Comment: @jxh no it does not, try to compile that.

Comment: @Slava: [Here you go.](http://ideone.com/lrqEZh)

Comment: @jxh yea right, now try to include header that has original `typedef struct { ... } crap;` - http://ideone.com/gbD53f

Comment: @Slava: Of course a syntax error is a syntax error. There is a difference between `struct crap {}` and an anonymous `struct {}`. The header file does not define the structure, but the library implementation provides a real definition for `struct crap`. http://ideone.com/1kgEB5

Comment: @jxh Ias you can see that it does not work with anonymous struct what I actually mention in my post, so it does not work and I cannot change header of 3rd party library to make structs non anonymous.

Comment: @Slava: You do not gain anything from using `void *` as the handle type other than avoiding the work of creating a proper type-safe thin wrapper. My comments indicate it is possible to create a type-safe wrapper, even if the wrapper has to inherit from the anonymous type in its implementation.

Comment: @jxh your example uses non anonymous structure so your comments do not indicate that it is possible.

Comment: @Slava: I am simply leaving the work of actually writing a type safe wrapper in your hands. If you are unclear as to how to proceed, feel free to post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
main()
```

This should be `int main(void)`.

```
{
    Minion *dummy = (Minion *)malloc(sizeof(Minion));
```

This is more clearly and reliably written as:

```
Minion *dummy = malloc(sizeof *dummy);
```

...

```
    dummy->father = &dummy;
    dummy->home = 0;
```

That's ok.

```
    printf("%d %d %d", &dummy, dummy->father, (dummy->father)->father);
```

You have several problems here.

`dummy` is a pointer object. `&dummy` is the address of that pointer object. The pointer object is allocated on the stack, and there's no particular reason to care about its address.

If you want to print the address of the `Minion` object you allocated, change `&dummy` to just `dummy`; you want the *value* of the pointer object.

`%d` is used only for printing values of type `int`, not pointers. To print a pointer value, use `%p`, which expects an argument of type `void*`, so in general you'll have to convert the pointer value to `void*` before printing it. That line should look like this:

```
printf("%p %p %p\n",
       (void*)dummy,
       (void*)dummy->father,
       (void*)dummy->father->father);
```

Note that I've added a `\n` to the end of the line so it will print properly. I've also removed an unnecessary set of parentheses.

```
}
```

One more minor point, not relevant to your problem.  It's common to define a `typedef` for each `struct` type -- but it's not necessary. My own personal preference is to omit the `typedef` and refer to the structure type by its original name -- in this case, `struct minion`. It's simpler (since it's easier to refer to the type before it's been completely defined). It's a little more typing, but IMHO the code is clearer if struct types are visibly structures. (It makes sense to use a typedef if you want the type to be *opaque*, so that code using the type doesn't know that it's a structure. You're not doing that here.)

On the other hand, plenty of C programmers prefer to use typedefs for structures because it provides a name for the type that's a single identifier. Pick a style and be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct minion
{
    int home;
    struct minion *father;  
} Minion;
main()
{
    Minion *dummy = (Minion *)malloc(sizeof(Minion));
    /* dummy->father = &dummy <== already a pointer */
    dummy->father = dummy;
    dummy->home = 0;
    printf("%p %p %p", dummy, dummy->father, (dummy->father)->father);
}
```

Comment: yeah its better to use %p but it doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: @E.Pajouheshgar removing & from dummy does and he already showed that to you.

Comment: `%p` expects an argument of type `void*`. See my answer.